# Проблема с производительностью при отрисовке UI на Samsung Galaxy s6

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml, samsung

При тестировании приложения среди ряда устройств возникла проблема с Samsung Galaxy s6 (Android v7). Наблюдается высокая загрузка GPU при прокрутке страницы, что негативно отражается на производительности. Фреймрейт падает при наличии в горизонтальном контейнере более 2-х элементов, содержащих изображение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/container_global_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="328dp"
                app:layout_columnSpan="3"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/container_global_2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/container_1"
                    android:layout_width="89dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="33%">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/e1"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:text="@string/test"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/container_2"
                    android:layout_width="152dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/container_1"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="33%">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/e3"
                        app:layout_column="1"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:text="@string/test"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/container_3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/container_2"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="368dp"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="312dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:src="@drawable/img1"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/test"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.513"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Этот и другие блоки находятся внутри **ScrollView**.
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: constraintlayout специально задумывался, как одноуровневый контейнер , то есть во всей разметке должен быть только один корневой контейнер (лэйаут) и констрайнты (связи) между виджетами в нем. поддерживает он и процентные отношения. Не скажу, что именно в этом проблема, но такая вложенность довольно тяжелых контейнеров точно не идет на пользу производительности, тем более в такой простой и линейной верстке. начать стоит с оптимизации разметки.

Comment: @pavlofff, благодарю за совет